# aws alarm to stop instance not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 ec2 instances, and I've set an alarm on both to stop them when cpu utilisation is below 5% for 1 hour. This was set yesterday, but this morning I found that the instances were still up, although the alarms were in the ALARM state. Cloudwatch has this, which seems to suggest it tried to stop the instances and thought that was successful:

> {
>     "stateUpdateTimestamp": null,
>     "notificationResource": "arn:aws:swf:us-west-2:853995436733:action/actions/AWS_EC2.InstanceId.Stop/1.0",
>     "publishedMessage": null,
>     "error": null,
>     "actionState": "Succeeded"
>   }

I can ssh to the instances and they are definitely up, with an uptime of 22 hours (the above log entry is from 19 hours ago). Both are definitely backed by EBS volumes. Thoughts? Is there some way I can try this 'action/actions/AWS_EC2.InstanceId.Stop/1.0' thing on a command line to see what it says?

Comment: did you check if your CPU utilization was below 5 % continuously for 1 Hour as I don't think that happening more frequently

Comment: I've retried it with < 50% just to make sure. It's acting very buggy. Sometimes it will stop, othertimes it wont, after multiple restarts and recreates of the alarm

Comment: I should mention, these are test machines which are literally doing nothing. So cpu usage should be about zero

Comment: The problem is not the CPU utilization it is with the duration of 1 Hour. From my experience I have seen some time EC2 gets sudden spikes in CPU utilization due to unknown entities. So even if there is one spike in the CPU utilization the autoscaling clock starts again from that spike.

Comment: But I was using 'average cpu utilisation', so spikes shouldnt matter